# Torus name keeps changing - keeps on adding index suffix

Tags: python, mesh, objects

When I add say two planes together the planes get the names Plane, Plane.001 and so on. But when I add one, delete it and add the second plane, it gets the name as Plane. But for Torus, I am getting Torus.001. I have deleted and added several times but it goes on increasing the number. For this I am facing problem in accessing the Torus through python script. Can anyone please say the possible source for this error and the solution to it? I have checked its not happening with other Mesh objects.

Comment: @RayMairlot he is trying to use python to manipulate toruses, but because blender strangely names toruses with a number even when they don't need to have one he is not able to. I think this is a very good question because this issue seems only to be specific to the torus.

Comment: Hi. Please add any code relevant to your question into the question body. Thanks.